# I have created an app in flutter, but whenever i press the back button it redirects me back to the pages i had open instead of previous pages

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am very new to flutter. Learning the basics. But the back button is not working as it should in the app.
This my main.dart file:

```
 void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();  
 await Firebase.initializeApp();   
 runApp(MyApp());  
 }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override  
Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
return MaterialApp(

  theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.orange
  ),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: HomePage(),

   );
  }  
 }
```

Comment: How are you move to the next screen from main?

Comment: I have created an login authentication app. If login is successful it will redirect me to homepage. But when i am on homepage and pressed back button, it takes me back to login page instead on start page.

Comment: can you add more code, like the homepage code and the authentication page code? this would help us to solve your problem.

Comment: You can replace your login page by calling `pushReplacement` method when you navigate to a home screen.